# how to download a folder with multiple files from github with wget?

Tags: linux, wget

I'm trying to install a tool from github.
I want to download a folder that contains many files (but not other folders).

when I use only `wget [link]` I get one file that concatenate all files in the folder instead of separate files.
I tried using `-r` and `-np` options but it didn't help.

Will appreciate any help

Comment: does the link end with `/` ?

Comment: @signo no it doesnt

Comment: @Lala try by placing `/` at the end of the link, also if you want only the files in the specified folder use `wget -r -l1 --no-parent`

Comment: @signo Thanks, I tried but it only produce a sequence of 5-6 folders one in each other, and in the end an HTML file that concatenates all files in the folder I wanted. this is the link to the folder I want {https://github.com/szpiech/selscan/tree/master/src}

Comment: @signo I was able to do it with DownGit. Thanks!

Comment: @beat I was able to do it with DownGit. Thanks!